# How to update a string with values from other fields?

Tags: sql, mssql

I have a table containing a column with a string value, and 3 other columns with data. How do I replace parts of the string, with the value of the other 3 columns? I need to be able to iterate this over various entries as well.

***Data sample:***

```
  DocNum |   DMS   | DMSDatabase | DocumentID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
38213097 | DMS-OLD |    DB2      | !nrtdms:0:!session:DMS-OLD:!database:DB1:!document:373108696,1:
```

What I need the DocumentID column to be replaced with:

```
!nrtdms:0:!session:DMS-NEW:!database:DB2:!document:38213097,1:
```

Comment: Do your fields really have all that whitespace padding, or is that just visual formatting?

Comment: @steeldriver visual formatting

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the actual format of the data. Also where does `DMS-NEW` come from? is that just a fixed string?